# Impala vs Hive. How Impala circumvents MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

How is Impala able to achieve lower latency than Hive in query processing?

I was going through http://impala.apache.org/overview.html, where it is stated:

> To avoid latency, Impala circumvents MapReduce to directly access the
>   data through a specialized distributed query engine that is very
>   similar to those found in commercial parallel RDBMSs. The result is
>   order-of-magnitude faster performance than Hive, depending on the type
>   of query and configuration.

How Impala fetches the data without MapReduce (as in Hive)?

Can we say that Impala is closer to HBase and should be compared with HBase instead of comparing with Hive?

**Edit:**

Or can we say that as classically, Hive is on top of MapReduce and does require less memory to work on while Impala does everything in memory and hence it requires more memory to work by having the data already being cached in memory and acted upon on request?

Comment: May I know the reason for negating the question?

Comment: answers are getting upvotes, but the question is downvoted and reason not given... lolz man

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just read [Impala Architecture and Components](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_concepts.html)

> Impala is a massively parallel processing (MPP) database engine. It consists of different daemon processes that run on specific hosts.... Impala is different from Hive and Pig because it uses its own daemons that are spread across the cluster for queries.

It circumvents MapReduce containers by having a long running daemon on every node that is able to accept query requests. There is no singular point of failure that handles requests like HiveServer2; all impala engines are able to immediately respond to query requests rather than queueing up MapReduce YARN containers.

Impala however does rely on the Hive Metastore service because it is just a useful service for mapping out metadata stored in the RDBMS to the Hadoop filesystem. Pig, Spark, PrestoDB, and other query engines also share the Hive Metastore without communicating though HiveServer.

Data is not "already cached" in Impala. Similar to Spark, you must read the data into a large portion of memory in order for operations to be quick. Unlike Spark, the daemons and statestore services remain active for handling subsequent queries.

Impala can query HBase, but it is not similar in architecture and in my experience, a well designed HBase table is faster to query than Impala. Impala is probably closer to Kudu.

Also worth mentioning that it's not really recommended to use MapReduce Hive anymore. Tez is far better, and [Hortonworks states Hive LLAP is better than Impala](https://hortonworks.com/blog/3x-faster-interactive-query-hive-llap/), although as you quoted, it largely "depends on the type of query and configuration."

Answer (score 0):

Impala use "Impala Daemon" service to read data directly from the dataNode (it must be installed with the same hosts of dataNode) .he cache only the location of files and some statistics in memory not the data itself.

that why impala can't read new files created within the table . you must invalidate or refresh (depend on your case) to tell impala to cache the new files and be able to read them directly

since impala is in memory , you need to have enough memory for the data read by the query , if you query will use more data than your memory (complexe query with aggregation on huge tables),use hive with spark engine not the default map reduce

`set hive.execution.engine=spark;` just before the query

you can use the same query  in hive with spark engine

impala is cloudera product , you won't find  it for hortonworks and MapR (or others) .

Tez is not included with cloudera for exemple.

it all depends on the platform you are using